# Scrapy - remove duplicates and output data as a single list?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the below code to crawl through multiple links on a page and grab a list of data from each corresponding link:

```
import scrapy

class testSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://www.website.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('div.subject_wrapper > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.getData)

    def getData(self, response):
        data = {'data': response.css('strong.data::text').extract()}
        yield data
```

It works fine, but as it's returning a list of data for each link, when I output to CSV it looks like the following:

```
"dalegribel,Chad,Ninoovcov,dalegribel,Gotenks,sillydog22"

"kaylachic,jmargerum,kaylachic"

"Kempodancer,doctordbrew,Gotenks,dalegribel"

"Gotenks,dalegribel,jmargerum"

...
```

Is there any simple/efficient way of outputting the data as a single list of rows without any duplicates (the same data can appear on multiple pages), similar to the following?

```
dalegribel
Chad
Ninoovcov
Gotenks
...
```

I have tried using an array then looping over each element to get an output, but get an error saying yield only supports 'Request, BaseItem, dict or None'. Also, as I would be running this over approx 10k entries, i'm not sure if storing the data in an array would slow the scrape down too much. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it can be somehow done using Scrapy built-in methods, but the python way would be to create a set of unique elements, check for duplicates, and yeild only unique elements:

```
class testSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://www.website.com']
    unique_data = set()

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('div.subject_wrapper > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.getData)

    def getData(self, response):
        data_list = response.css('strong.data::text').extract()
        for elem in data_list:
            if elem and (elem not in self.unique_data):
                self.unique_data.add(elem)
                yield {'data': elem}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got an error saying that the list attribute does not support `split` - so after removing this function it seemed to work fine, as the loop seemed to take care of the splitting. One thing that seems to be happening still however is the gaps between each row when exporting to CSV (same as shown above in the second block of code). Is there any way to fix this so there are no empty rows? Thank you.

Comment: @ExamOrph how is the data outputted to CSV? By function or what?

Comment: command line function: `scrapy crawl quotes -o test.csv -t csv`

Comment: @ExamOrph It seems that were are adding empty elements to the file. Maybe we need to check if `elem` is not empty. And yes, I just checked Scrapy  docs. `.extract()` does `.split()` for us. Try my updated code.

Comment: Thanks I get the same thing, maybe it's a Windows issue, as i'm on Windows 10 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477662/scrapy-csv-file-has-uniform-empty-rows)?

Comment: Also, i'm running the commands through the Anaconda Prompt which might have something to do with it?

Comment: @ExamOrph, I checked your link. Yes, it may be somehow connected with versioning and all these things. I think so because even before we changed any code it added blank lines (your first example). And your code was rather straightforward, pure Scrapy built-in methods. Not the best advice, but if you use this script for one time scraping, just write another small script that deletes blank lines.

Comment: Thanks, it's easy enough to remove blanks using excel anyways - so should be ok. I have one more question please, if you don't mind - if I am scraping large amounts of data (10k entries) would storing a set() of unique_data in memory as you have done make a noticeable difference in performance? I ask because, if so, I could always just remove this and leave the duplicates then later use excel to remove these, if that would be faster?

Comment: @ExamOrph sets are designed to store unique values, and actually, 10k isn't that much. If python doesn't use this memory, then Exel will. If you don't run the script on a wooden PC, I think you will have no problems with it. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577790/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-values-that-a-python-set-can-contain

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of data! I've recently moved over from VBA/VB Script so this is all 'new technology' to me! Thanks again for all the help - very much appreciated.